# Is the sum of two sine waves periodic?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

> Is the sum of two sine waves periodic? Specifically, what will be the period of $\sin(mx)+\sin(nx)$ where $m$ and $n$ are real constants?

When $m$ and $n$ are integers, it is not difficult to show by definition that $\sin(mx)+\sin(nx)$ is periodic. But I don't know how to handle the general cases. Can anyone help?

Comment: It depends on $m,n$. Are they integers? rationals? irrational?

Comment: m and n are real numbers.

Comment: then it depends on the ratio $m/n$: whether it is rational or irrational.

Comment: I'd take the ratio to be a real number as well. I don't get how it makes a difference. Any explanations would be helpful.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873723/how-to-find-the-period-of-the-sum-of-two-trigonometric-functions

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384746/can-the-sum-of-two-periodic-functions-with-non-commensurate-periods-be-a-periodi).

Answer (score 27):

If  $m>0$, $n>0$ and the ratio $\dfrac{m}{n}$ is **rational**:
$$
\dfrac{m}{n} = \dfrac{a}{b}, \qquad a,b\in\mathbb{N},
$$
then the function $$f(x)=\sin(mx)+\sin(nx)\tag{1}$$
is $T$-periodic, where $$T = \dfrac{2\pi}{r\cdot GCD(a,b)},\tag{2}$$
where $r=\dfrac{m}{a} = \dfrac{n}{b}$, and $GCD(a,b)$ means [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of $a,b$.

To see that the function $f(x)$ is $T$-periodic, calculate the value $f(x+T)$:

$$f(x+T) = \\ \sin(ar(x+T))+\sin(br(x+T)) = \\ 
\sin\left(arx+ar\cdot \dfrac{2\pi}{r\cdot GCD(a,b)}\right)+
\sin\left(brx+br\cdot \dfrac{2\pi}{r\cdot GCD(a,b)}\right) = \\ 
\sin\left(arx+a_1 \cdot 2\pi\right)+
\sin\left(brx+b_1 \cdot 2\pi\right)= \\
\sin(arx)+
\sin(brx)= \\ f(x),$$
since $\;a_1=\dfrac{a}{GCD(a,b)}\in\mathbb{N}$, $\;b_1=\dfrac{b}{GCD(a,b)}\in\mathbb{N}$.

Note: there is the reason to write the ratio $\dfrac{m}{n}$ in the form $\dfrac{m}{n}=\dfrac{a}{b}$, where $\dfrac{a}{b}$ is **[irreducible fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_fraction)**; in this case expression $(2)$ will have simpler form:
$$
T = \dfrac{2\pi}{r}.\tag{2'}
$$

---

A bit more complicated is to show that the formula $(2)$ determines *the smallest possible* value for period.

---

If the ratio $\dfrac{m}{n}$ is **irrational**, then $f(x)$ isn't periodic. There should be some theorems related to this theme, but I cannot remember any. 

Intuitively, for any irrational number $\alpha=\dfrac{m}{n}$ we can focus on its [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) and consider infinite sequence of its convergents $\left\{ \dfrac{a_1}{b_1},\dfrac{a_2}{b_2},\dfrac{a_3}{b_3}, \ldots \right\}$ to see '*almost periodic*' behavior of such function $f(x)$.

Update: See **Micah**'s elegant sketch of proof in the comments (concerning irrational $m/n$).

---

To feel the difference between rational and irrational ratio $\dfrac{m}{n}$, 
consider $m=6+ \varepsilon$, $n = 2 $, where $\varepsilon$ is very small irrational value.
Then the continued fraction of the ratio $\alpha = \dfrac{m}{n}$ will have the form $$[3; c_1, c_2, \ldots ],\tag{3}$$
where $c_1$ is large number, other $c_j$ are just positive integer numbers.

Roughly, if consider $1$st convergent $\dfrac{a_1}{b_1}=\dfrac{3}{1}$, then function $f_1(x) = \sin(6x)+\sin(2x)$ has period $\pi$.

But focus on $c_1$: $2$nd convergent is $\dfrac{a_2}{b_2}=\dfrac{3c_1+1}{c_1}$, and function $f_2(x)=\sin\left( 6+\dfrac{2}{c_1} \right)x+\sin(2x)$ will have period $c_1\pi$.

 If we focus on $c_2$, then period of $f_3(x)$ will be even larger.
And so, each step we will have larger and larger period...

In the case if $\varepsilon$ is rational, the continued fraction $(3)$ is finite, so the process above (of increasing periods) for rational $\varepsilon$ is finite too, then we will stop at certain (large) period.

Comment: Nice answer this!

Comment: If $m/n$ is irrational, then $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x)=m+n$ if and only if $x=0$. So $f$ cannot be periodic.

Comment: The case of irrational $m/n$ is one of the motivating examples of [almost periodic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function).

Comment: To prove that the value $T$ (described by $(2)$) is *the smallest* value of possible periods in the case of rational $m/n$, one can use trick mentioned by @Micah (thanks!): consider $f'$ and show that the smallest positive solution of eq. $f'(x)=m+n$ is $x=T$.

Comment: FYI: I have voted to reopen this post. If you find this question worth answering, as I do, please vote to reopen it as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Micah Is this method still working when m > 0 and n < 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

The period of $\sin(n_1x)$ is $T_1 =\tfrac{2\pi}{n_1}$ and that of $T_2 =\sin(n_2x)$ is $\tfrac{2\pi}{n_2}$. These are the lengths on the real line after which the functions repeat. For combined period, we need the smallest value so that

$$n_1T_1 = n_2 T_2$$

where $n_1, n_2 \in \Bbb Z$. Thus as Oleg said, we need $\tfrac{T_1}{T_2} \in \Bbb Q$ for the sum to be periodic.

Comment: You might want to change $n$ and $m$ to $n_1$ and $n_2$ or vice versa

Comment: @infinite oops completely missed. Thanks a lot!